# Android Studio: I want remove the comma in the number, but after I remove the comma, the output become weird

Tags: java, android-studio

I had removed the comma in the number, but after I remove the comma, the output become weird.
I implemented this code but getting weird for the output number like I inputing 333333.33 will come out with 333333.34.
How to solve this problem? Anyone can help me?

```
binding.invdtlUnitpriceTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if (s.length() == 0) {
                    invoiceDetails.setUPrice(0.00f);
                    return;
                }

                binding.invdtlUnitpriceTxt.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                /*
                 * Clear input to get clean text before format
                 * '\u0020' is empty character
                 */
                String text = s.toString();
                String result = "";
                text = text.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");

                try {
                    text = format(text);
                    result = text.replace("," ,"");
                    invoiceDetails.setUPrice(Float.parseFloat(result));
                    Calculation();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getCanonicalName(), e.getMessage());
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getCanonicalName(), e.getMessage());
                }

                binding.invdtlUnitpriceTxt.setText(result);
                binding.invdtlUnitpriceTxt.setSelection(result.length());

                binding.invdtlUnitpriceTxt.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
```

Comment: Good morning. What does `format(text)` do? Could you post the code?

Comment: @Enzo Hi, I got updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example of this behaviour is:

```java
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("333333.33"));
// outputs 333333.34

System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("666666.66"));
// outputs 666666.7

System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("111111.11"));
// outputs 111111.11, it actually works!
```

This is related to floating-point precision. See the same code, but now with `Double`:

```java
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("333333.33"));
// outputs 333333.33
        
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("666666.66"));
// outputs 666666.66

System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("111111.11"));
// outputs 111111.11
```

Double is [double-precision value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3), therefore it's more accurate.

But if you're leading with money in a real situation, always use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Actually if I no remove the comma, it can work well. If I removed the comma, the output become well.

Answer (score 0):

`invoiceDetails.setUPrice(Float.parseFloat(result));` here is the issue.
Your result value is round off while you are converting it to float. If you are setting a value to a textview please set without conversion.
`textview.settext(result);`
Hope it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

I think the in output 333333.34 the 4 in end usually means that the 3 will continue to infinity. Eg- 333333.333333333(so on)

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry to say that but unfortunately I have a strong feeling that you're wrong.